# Misaligned Columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 32,000 rows of data. Each row contains some key-value pairs. Some key-value pairs are missing in certain rows. When a key-value pair is missing, it is replaced by the key-value pair to the immediate right. For this reason, the columns are misaligned. I would like all key-values pairs with the same key to be in the same column.

Here is a screenshot illustrating the problem:

[image: Misaligned columns]

How can I achieve this transformation programmatically?

Comment: In general, it is best to not post pictures if you can avoid it. A lot of people have the image site blocked and can't help you.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know and thank you.

Comment: I don't see how the columns are misaligned. Also, it's not clear what your method is to go from red to green. You seem to be using the attribute from the first line in red to become the first one in green. Do you exclude the rest? Put them on a list? Are you filling them in by previous position, if it exists?

Comment: @rajah9 Compare line 3 with line 9 and line 5 with line 11.  OP wants all the Color: in A and Size: in B and Quality in C and Taste: in D.  OP has the data like the first red block and wants the data to be setup like the second block in green.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use a table that has column headers instead of the value pairs.  So the first column header would be `color` and then the cells in that column would only be the color, such as "blue", "red", "green", "black", and "red".  Is there any particular reason you need the key-value pairs?

Comment: This is going to require vba.  What have you tried?

Comment: @sandpiper not always the case; sometimes pictures can provide context to peoples' posts, which can be needed if the code is complex.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I could infer most of the rules by looking at the example. But I'd rather have the OP explicitly state the rules in his/her question or an edit instead of several of us inferring. And I think an explicit statement would increase the quality of the question.

Comment: @rajah9 I see your point.

Comment: @rajah9 Ok, I will attempt to elaborate without stating the obvious and insulting everyone's intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a 0 options (or NA) option. So instead of setting the size value to not be there, set the size value to be 0. To easily figure out which ones don't have this value, you could do a filter-> sort -> copy paste, then initialize all of them as default. It will expand the amount of data you need to store, but in the future if you need to update the rows it might be easier to do so.

Comment: And if the data comes from a txt file or other source that the OP has no control over?

Comment: I'm assuming that OP has a way to turn, for instance, a long string of text (IE "color: blue, size: big, quality: 3, taste: salty") into a column based format where each of those elements has their own column. Or that OP can manipulate the data in some way. To check if such an item exists (IE size) OP could use =if((find("size", cell reference)>0, don't do anything, do something)

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click the sheet > `View Code` > paste the code from below (not tested) and Run (F5)

```
Sub align()
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long, likes()
    likes = Array("", "color: *", "size: *", "quality: *", "taste: *")
    For Each cell In Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(values)
            If Not cell(, i) Like likes(i) Then cell(, i).Insert xlToRight
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```